# Vuejs ajax GET request not returning data in Laravel 5.1 Blade template

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-resource

am trying to retrieve data from a database using  [vuejs](https://vuejs.org) ajax call with a plugin called [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource). Unfortunately, the json data object contains the html page and not the actual data from the database. Can someone please tell me what am doing wrong?
This is my code:

routes.php

```
    <?php
Route::get('find', 'FruitsCtrl@index');
```

fruitsctrl.php (controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Fruit;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class FruitsCtrl extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $req){
        $fruits = Fruit::all();
        return view('fruitsHome', $fruits);
    }
}
```

fruit.php (model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Fruit extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
            'id', 'name', 'type'
    ];
}
```

fruitshome.blade.php (view)

```
<head>
        <meta id="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row" id="vapp">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="fruit in fruits">
                @{{ fruit.name }}
                @{{ fruit.type }}

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<body>
```

app.js (javascript)

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content');
var v = new Vue({
    el : "#vapp",
    ready :function () {
        this.fetchFruits();
    },
    data : {
        fruit : {id:'', name:'', type:''},
        fruits : []
    },
    methods : {
        fetchFruits : function(){
            this.$http.get('/find').then(function(res){
                this.fruits = res;
            },function (data){
                console.log(error ...);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently returning a view from your controller:

```
class FruitsCtrl extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $req){
        $fruits = Fruit::all();
        return view('fruitsHome', $fruits);
    }
}
```

Instead, you can return the Eloquent results directly and they'll be output as JSON:

```
class FruitsCtrl extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $req){
        $fruits = Fruit::all();
        return $fruits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set table name in the model like this :

```
class Fruit extends Model
{

   protected $table = 'fruits';
   protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'type'
   ];
}
```

You also need to update index method like this :

```
public function index(Request $req){
    $fruits = Fruit::all();
    return view('fruitsHome')->withFruits($fruits);
}
```

and finally update the blade :

```
       <li v-for="fruits in fruit">
            @{!! $fruits->name !!}
            @{!! $fruits->type !!}

        </li>
```

Let me know if it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried your suggestion but it does not work. I am receiving an error exception in illuminate\View\View.php. The error is illegal offset type...